# Persist huge data structure

Tags: xml, data-structures, persistence, large-data

I have an object that internally has multiple child objects which in turn have child objects. Today this data structure is persisted as XML in DB String column. I'm looking at an option of flattening this. Persisting into DB tables will make it very complex considering that about 20-30 tables will have to be created and maintaining this in java requires extremely careful handling of transactions.

Is there any way we can persist this data which will make it query friendly and also easy to maintain just like DB tables?

Comment: The XML should look exactly like the db.  The top level XML tag is the database name.  The next level of tags are the table names.  The 3rd level of tags is the fields in the database.  Keeping the XML to three layer of tags ill make it easy to serialize/de-serialize the database.

Comment: You can look at a database really as a flat file with all the tables joined.  The tables are a convenient way of viewing pieces of the database.